# Pass dynamic javascript variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I wanna pass a JavaScript variable in to PHP, that's my code:

```
$('.info-button').on('click', function() {
         var flag = $(this).data('flag');

            if (flag) {
                var index3 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('img').attr('src');
                console.log(index3);
              $('.inner').css("display", "block");
            } else {
                    $('.inner').css("display", "none");
            }

            $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
```

How to get index3, which is dynamic variable from PHP?

I tried with:

```
<?php
   echo "<script>document.writeln(index3);</script>";
?>
```

But Im getting **index3 is not defined**

Comment: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming).

Comment: Check about AJAX